# How to make ListView and ImageView scrollable into LinearLayout?

Tags: android, listview, scroll, imageview, android-linearlayout

I have `LinearLayout` compoment which contains `ListView` and `ImageView`.

According to the documentation layout area should be scrollable if element's height is bigger than LinearLayout's area.

But scroll is not available.

I can scroll only when listview contains a lot of elements. But in this case `ImageView` component **is not visible at all**.

Using `ScrollView` is not allowed because `ListView` has his own Scroll element.

Could you please advice what should I do?

Here is part of my xml file:

```xml
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_below="@id/top_header" 
              android:layout_above="@id/bottom_menu"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:id="@+id/sub_content_view">

    <ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/eventsListView"/>

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="260dp"
            android:id="@+id/empty_area"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/empty_area"
            android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `ListView` is not empty, you may register the `ImageView` as [list footer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29), it then scrolls with the `ListView`. However, footers are not displayed if the list is empty, so you'd have to add the `ImageView` to the empty view as well.

Answer (score 0):

First 2 comments than a possible solution

(1) `ListView` won't be scrollable when there's nothing in it. Instead it will display an empty view which you can set either programaticlly or with XML (usualy a text view that says something to the extent of "your list is empty").

(2) Your `ImageView` is set for a fixed height while your `ListView` is set to `wrap_content`. As a result, when your `ListView` contains enough elements that is is larger than the area of the screen it will push your `ImageView` out of view. As I have yet to see a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` suddnely become scrollable if there's more stuff on the screen than there is space (I just tried to make it happen) I'm not surprised by what you're describing.

You're right that using a `ScrollView` with a `ListView` as a child is disfavored. What I would try is - instead of putting both the `ListView` and `ImageView` in the same `LinearLayout` - separate the two. I don't know the rest of your XML but if you moved the `ImageView` out of that layout element you should be able to position it below the part containing the `ListView` such that - regardless of the size of the list - the `ImageView` will remain in the same place.

The suggestion above to use a footer may work, however, a `footer` is pinned to the bottom of the list. That means, if your list is really long, there will be a point at which the `footer` is not visible unless you scroll down far enough that it is exposed. If you want the image to remain visible all the time, e.g. have the list scroll behind the image, then you need to use a different approach.